# Giving inputs to java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex like below one :

```
"\\t'AUR +(username) .*? /ROLE=\"(my_role)\".*$"
```

**username** and **my_role** parts will be given from args. So they always change when the script is starting. So how can i give parameters to that part of regex ?

Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

Define regex like this:

```
String fmt = "\\t'AUR +(%s) .*? /ROLE=\"(%s)\".*$";

// assuming userName and myRole are your arguments
String regex = String.format(fmt, userName, myRole);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should escape special characters in dynamic strings using [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29). To put the regex parts together you can simply use string concatenation like this:

```
String quotedUsername = Pattern.quote(username);
String quotedRole = Pattern.quote(my_role);
String regexString = "\\t'AUR +(" + quotedUsername + 
                     ") .*? /ROLE=\"(" + quotedRole + ")\".*$";
```

I think mixing regular expressions with format strings when using `String.format` can make the regex harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use string format or straight string concat to construct the regex before passing it to compile ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this for an example:

```
String patternString = "\\t'AUR +(%s) .*? /ROLE=\"(%s)\".*$";
String formatted = String.format(patternString, username,my_role);
System.out.println(formatted);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
```

You can run a working example here: http://ideone.com/93YeNg